# Unable to find the class on dex path list

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

I see a lot of questions like this but none of them helped me to solve the issue. 
What's my issue is Android Studio able to build apk successfully but when I run it on my device it crashes.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application io.tutorial.app.App: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.tutorial.app.App" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/io.tutorial.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.tutorial.app-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/io.tutorial.app-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:811)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5504)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1611)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.tutorial.app.App" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/io.tutorial.app-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.tutorial.app-1/lib/arm64, /data/app/io.tutorial.app-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74)
```

And below is the part of manifest file.

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app"
    android:name="io.tutorial.app.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

    <activity
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarFullScreen"
        android:name=".ui.activity.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Instant run is turned off. Tested after invalidating caches and rebuild project. Generated signed APK and tried but same issue. I used analyze APK in Android Studio and I found there are two dex files 1.classes.dex 2. classes2.dex.

Below is the Part code of App.java class

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {
@Inject
Cache cache;

public void onCreate() {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
    super.onCreate();
    initRemoteConfig();
    Injector.getInstance().init(this);
    Injector.getInstance().appComponent().inject(this);
    initFabric();
    initRealm();
    initPicasso();
    initRemoteConfig();
    initAds();
    initOneSignal();
}
```

Comment: have you enabled multidex in your gradle?

Comment: Yes, I've enabled multidex.

Comment: I don't know why people downvoting this. I asked my question clearly. I mentioned all things correctly, but why!!!

Comment: is there any class on this path? io.tutorial.app.App

Comment: Yes App is a class which is present at io.tutorial.app directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any class that is extending default Application class then change it as below

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication
```

or you override attachBaseContext as below:

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
 super.attachBaseContext(base);
 MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

Comment: I added some part of the code from App.java class. App class is already extending multidex

Comment: Actually I think "io.tutorial.app" directory should not present in classes2.dex file. Because there is nothing in "io.tuttorial.app" directory in classes2.dex everything is present at classes.dex file.